Verbal bracketting with Genitive

Aufgabe: Nominaliserung des Verbes
In der Mechatronik wird Wissen aus der Mechanik und der Elektrotechnik kombiniert
My attempt: Die Kombination des aus der Mechanik und der Elektrotechnik Wissens in der Mechatronik
Correct answer: Die Kombinerung von Wissen aus der Mechanik und der Elektrotechnik in der Mechatechnik

Why exactly is my answer wrong? Is it inappropriate to use verbal bracketting?

There simply is no verbal bracketing in your fragments because there is no verb.

You have used a definitive article ("des Wissens") - This implies "all of the knowledge", while you want to say "some of it" - for the "some of it", you'd be using the indefinite article which would degrade to the Nullartikel (i.e. none at all) in your specific example. The original sentence also uses the Nullartikel.

The definite article is not next to the noun it correlates with. It should be "...Kombination des Wissens aus...". With the flexible German word order, you need to place the article immediately in front of the related noun, otherwise its not clear where it belongs to (but see (1) why "des" is wrong). Your sentence in correct word order would be

Die Kombination des Wissens aus der Mechanik und Elektrotechnik...

But again, that would mean "all of it"


Just as a side note you didn't ask for. You have used both "Kombinierung" and "Kombination" and might wonder whether there is a difference. Both are valid (even if "Kombinierung" would be very rarely used). "Kombinierung" would be used in rare cases where you are referring to the act of combining, while "Kombination" more refers to the end result (but could also be used for both). Just like "combining" and "combination" in English.


Is it inappropriate to use verbal bracketting?

Yeah. Because you don't have a verb. What you have there is a plain noun phrase.
There are two valid alternatives:

die Kombination des Wissens aus der Mechanik und der Elektrotechnik
die Kombination von Wissen aus der Mechanik und der Elektrotechnik

The first uses a genitive attribute that is explained further by an appended adverbial of origin. The second does the same with an adverbial of attendance  that is explained further by an appended adverbial of origin.
You could also write

die Kombination des Mechanik-Wissens und (des) Elektrotechnik-Wissens
die Kombination des Mechanik- und Elektrotechnik-Wissens
die Kombination von Mechanik-Wissen und (von) Elektrotechnik-Wissen
die Kombination von Mechanik- und Elektrotechnik-Wissen

and conflate the adverbial of origin into a list of alternative compound nouns. But as you can see that requires you to skip aus so the meaning is slighty different.

If you wanted verbal bracketing, you would have to introduce a participle:

die Kombination des aus der Mechanik und der Elektrotechnik gewonnenen Wissens

That's valid and you will encounter such brackets pretty often.
